# Store OUT parameter from One Procedure to Another and then Pass it to XSJS in HANA

Tags: stored-procedures, procedure, hana

I Have two Procedures:

**Procedure 1:**

```
pqr (In a INT)
begin
 CALL xyz(a);
END;
```

**Procedure 2:**

```
 xyz (IN a INT, OUT trace "alpha"."Trace_Record") 
BEGIN
Some Logic;
END;
```

`"alpha"."Trace_Record"` is a **TABLE TYPE** and is returning record to procedure 1.

Is there any way to store the table type in the Procedure 1.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign the out parameter to a table variable anyhow in order to call proc2...:

```
call proc2 (:int_value, :my_table_var);
```

my_table_var will now point to the trace_record type table.

Comment: Thanks.! Solved it..:)